# Prevent Spammers from posting on site for forms not secured by a logged in ID

Tags: php, validation, spam

All,
I have a guestbook feature on my site and I keep getting spammed. I'm doing validation on the front end with the jquery validator and asking a math question to ensure it's not a spamming tool. I also have a hidden field that generates a random number (a Form Key) in my POST request.

On the backend I verify the form key and I also check the values against some select words function and I also say if isset($_POST). I still keep getting spammed pretty bad and not sure how I can avoid this anymore. Other then making people register for the site, how can I prevent all the spam? Any additional suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use a better captcha such as Re-Captcha by Google.
2. Create a honey pot field that you hide with CSS. Bots typically fill in all fields, so if this hidden field is filled in, you know it's a bot.

Comment: Oooh, I like the honey pot field idea too.  Would have never thought about that.

Comment: @dqhendricks Just as an additional FYI, I was still getting spam posts so I decided to actually put the CSS in jQuery and hide the form field that way. I'll report back and see if that is more successful.

Comment: @user1048676 you are rejecting the requests that have that field filled out right? also, you really need re-captcha above all else.

Comment: @dqhendricks I sure am I included empty($_POST['lamecaptcha']) in my if logic on when to process the form. I had the reCaptcha as well and it still spammed. Nothing happened for a little now that I added the CSS for that hidden form into my jQuery

Comment: @user1048676 if re-captcha isn't stopping them, you are doing something seriously wrong with your input validation, or it is a human spamming.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it in practice, but one thing you could do is to make use of the fact that the robots are posting the forms awfully fast. You could have a hidden field and adding a timestamp to it when you render the page. After the post, on the server-side, you check the timestamp and if it is less than say five seconds off, it is not likely that it is a human post.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my list of checks as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with some forms I had but approached it differently, adding a form field that **has** to be empty to submit. I found that most of the bots presumed that they needed to fill in all text fields to be able to submit the form. What I do is add form fields that a real user should never see and make sure they stay empty in the $_POST.

http://aknosis.com/2009/04/17/zero-user-interaction-captcha/

Answer (score 0):

Put recaptcha on it.  http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: The user is already using a mathematical CAPTCHA so I don't know why recaptcha would fare any better.

Comment: Thanks, but why is a recaptcha better then asking a math question? Can robots read a hidden field and actually enter that value into a form field? I was thinking a math problem and a recaptcha both show that it's a human entering the form.

Comment: Because robots can read text.  Also, if he is storing the final math value in a hidden field and submitting it with the form, the robots only have to scrape the page for that hidden field name and pull the value from it.  So the robot would know what to put in as the answer.

Comment: Yes, robots can read everything you output to the browser, including hidden fields.

Comment: @user1048676 Yes.  Sorry, you asked while I was replying to j08691.

Comment: If I verified and answer with ajax instead of having it in a hidden field would that also work so the answer is hosted externally?

Comment: @user1048676 Well if you stored your values directly in your script code itself, it would help.  But you'd still have to display them on the page.  I don't know how much scripting bots see or anything, but placing the values in the right places after the page loads would definitely help.  So if you had no hidden field, use jquery or javascript to place the math numbers into their span tags (or whatever they are in), then used jquery/javascript to grab all the field values and process it with ajax including the math numbers, it would definitely make it a lot harder for a bot.